# Sum the total amount of a specific product purchased per user and display in table

Tags: php, woocommerce-offtopic, mysql, table

I asked this in Stackoverflow but figured this would be a more specific domain to answer my question...

I have a large mysql table (in woocommerce) where people can purchase items more than once.

My goal is to be able to group the quantity of the product purchased by user_id so that each row is user and product specific.

```
user ID | Product | quantity | billing address 
23      | chair   | 4        | 22 Bank street
42      | chair   | 12       | 123 Smith Road
88      | chair   | 5        | 3 Parker avenue
```

etc

I found [this](http://codecharismatic.com/sql-script-to-get-all-woocommerce-orders-including-metadata/) code, but have been unable to generate the table I would need. In future, I would like to add the ability to only show specific products in the table (via SKU) and perhaps their status. I would add drop down menus to dynamically alter the sql query so the table generates what I want. But figuring out how to get the table to generate in the first place is my number one priority!

```
<?php 
if (!is_user_logged_in() || !current_user_can('manage_options')) wp_die('This page is private.');

$con=mysqli_connect("ip","user","pass","database");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
$result = mysqli_query($con,
"select p.user_id,
       max( CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = '_sku' and p.ID = pm.post_id THEN pm.meta_value END ) as _sku,
       max( CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = '_amount' and p.ID = pm.post_id THEN pm.meta_value END ) as _amount,
       max( CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = '_billing_address_1' and p.ID = pm.post_id THEN pm.meta_value END ) as _billing_address_1,
       group_concat(distinct oi.order_item_name separator '|' ) as order_items
from wp_posts p join
    wp_postsmeta pm
    on p.ID = pm.post_id join
    wp_woocommerce_order_items oi
where p.post_type = 'shop_order' and
      p.post_status = 'wc-completed' and
      oi.order_item_name = 'Product Name'
group p.user_id");
echo "<table>";
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
echo "<tr style='font-size: 0.665em'>";
echo "<td>"  . $row['user_id'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['amount'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['billing_address_1'] . "</td>";
echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
?>
```

Comment: _I have a large mysql table (in woocommerce)_ --- Do you mean _i have a woocommerce shop with products_ OR do you really have a custom DB table? Don't use `mysqli` in WP, use `$wpdb`, `new WP_Query($args)` or `get_posts($args)` to get data from the DB.

Comment: Nope, its the standard woocommerce tables. I was advised against using those commands... Would they work? Can I use sum arguments with them?

Comment: Actually I would need to make SUM() and GROUP arguments... I've yet to find any info on this/how

Comment: I'm working on a ready to go code snippet for you wait a few minuts

Comment: Awesome, thanks @Bjorn I've been wrestling this idea for a while...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### WooCommerce: Get Order info for all users.

I was trying to help you get going.. After a while i had a complete solution :S...

So here it is, a tested single shortcode that outputs your `<table>` (WooCommerce 3+ only):

```
add_shortcode('user_order_info_table', 'sc_user_order_info_table_callback');
function sc_user_order_info_table_callback() {

  $result_array = array();
  $users = get_users();

  if($users) {

    foreach ($users as $user) {
      $products_ordered = array();

      $order_args = array(
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'meta_key'    => '_customer_user',
        'meta_value'  => $user->ID,
        'post_type'   => 'shop_order',
        'post_status' => 'wc-completed', // only get completed orders
      );
      $orders = get_posts($order_args);

      if($orders) {
        foreach ($orders as $order) {
          $wc_order = wc_get_order( $order->ID );

          foreach ($wc_order->get_items() as $product) {
            $wc_product = wc_get_product($product->get_product_id());

            if($wc_product) { // make sure the product still exists
              if( ! isset( $products_ordered[$product->get_product_id()] ) ) {
                $products_ordered[$product->get_product_id()] = array(
                  'name' => $product->get_name(),
                  'qty' => $product->get_quantity(),
                );
              } else {
                $products_ordered[$product->get_product_id()]['qty'] = $products_ordered[$product->get_product_id()]['qty'] + $product->get_quantity();
              }

              // get sku example
              //$wc_product->get_sku();
            }
          }
        }
      }

      $customer = new WC_Customer( $user->ID );
      $billing_data = $customer->get_billing('view');
      $user_billing_address1 = $billing_data['address_1'];

      // we have collected all data, save it to array
      $result_array[$user->ID] = array(
        'products_ordered' => $products_ordered,
        'address1' => $user_billing_address1,
      );

    }
  } else {

  }

  // shortcode html output begins hebrev
  $return_html = '<table><thead><tr><td>User ID</td><td>Product</td><td>Quantity</td><td>billing address 1</td></tr></thead><tbody>';

  foreach ($result_array as $user_id => $data) {
    if( isset($data['products_ordered']) && $data['products_ordered'] ) {
      foreach ($data['products_ordered'] as $product_id => $product_data) {
        $return_html .= '<tr>';
        $return_html .= '<td>'.$user_id.'</td>';
        $return_html .= '<td>'.$product_data['name'].'</td>';
        $return_html .= '<td>'.$product_data['qty'].'</td>';
        $return_html .= '<td>'.$data['address1'].'</td>';
        $return_html .= '</tr>';
      }
    }
  }

  $return_html .= '</tbody></table>';

  return $return_html;

}
```

Place this snippet in your ([child](https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes)) theme functions.php.

Use the shortcode `[user_order_info_table]` in posts and pages wherever you want.

See it @ work [here](https://so.enjoyitwebdesign.nl/wp-code-snippets/woocommerce/woocommerce-for-each-user-get-order-info/) in my sandbox.

NOTE: it works, but this is not a 'final release' ready for shipping. You probably want to do some more error handling etc.

Regards, Bjorn

Comment: one word. Legend.

Can I omit the functions.php and embed directly into my php page which is for admins only? The reason I ask is because I plan I using this data and manipulating it with additional commands (arithmetic calculations against the quantity integers). and then append it to a mySQL table

Comment: it depends. How are you loading that php file? Why a php file? If you want to restrict content on WP pages use a user control plugin like [members](https://nl.wordpress.org/plugins/members/). Create a page, set access to admin users only, and place my shortcode on that page and you're done. For extra protection, do current_user role checking inside my function. Please set my answer as accepted if you like it, thanks :-)!

Comment: For the total amount of products ordered per person, I want to be able to multiply it by a coefficient which I place in a textbox above the generated table, then a column will autogenerate the new variable (product of amount ordered * coeffiecient). My logic is so I do not need to make multiple pages for each product.. and i also like to learn more coding as I go, hence why I veere away from shortcodes whenever possible...

Comment: I would still use the shortcode, and with `wp_ajax` i would control the `<table>` on-the-fly. Ajax maybe a bit much now, keep things simple in the beginning. Also, i recommend you first learn how to debug code, google 'wp_debug'. It's the first thing developers do when code isn't working or does something unexpected. Good luck!

Comment: Cheers. I will definitely be trying to solve that riddle!

Comment: actually, I figured my issue... forgot something ... I have some additional ideas I wanna run by you

Comment: sent you an email... hopefully your business can suit our needs! :)